# R generate and bind row of time increase 10 mintues at time

Tags: r

I am a new user in R, I want to generate a new row with 145 columns which contain time in the following format : 00:00 00:10 00:20 .... 23:40 23:50. then bind it with my matrix.

I read about "POSIXlt" and "POSIXct" but I don't know how to adopt it.

sorry if my question is repeated , please point me where could I found the answer.

many thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `seq` to generate the sequence of 'DateTime', `format` it,

```
v1 <- format(seq(as.POSIXct("00:00:00", format = "%H:%M:%S"),
             length.out = 144, by = "10 min"), "%H:%M")
range(v1)
#[1] "00:00" "23:50"
```

and then `rbind` with your dataset. It may be better to keep it as a individual `vector`.  The OP did not show the original dataset.  So the `class` of the columns are not known, 'v1' is a `character` vector and `rbind`ing with the original data can change the `class` of the columns unnecessarily.

Comment: many thanks RHertel for your quick reply as you said it is worked but it  changed all matrix class to string as following :

X23.50 
"63.7" 
  "10.5" 

and the old one was:
X23.50
      63.7
       10.5

is there any way to keep it the same class without " " as the character with the time as well.
many thanks

Comment: @yaseen I did not answer this and I don't deserve credit here... It was akrun. All I have done was to correct a typo in the title.

Comment: Sorry RHertel. Thanks akrun for your help.please what you mean by "keep this as a vector". each time will be a symbol for a column in future. So , getting the time information is the half way (in the form of sequence of time for each 10 mins) thanks. After that, I need to summation the values in each column under this time(the time we found the sequence for 10 mins) . the problem now after binding the values become char and I can not do the summation. Follow.....

Comment: simply, I have the time sequence for every 10 mins 144 value. then I need to bind it with the matrix of 11 rows and 145 columns of rational numbers values. then do the summation for theses numbers. after that I need to determine which time for highest value.
so I think the solution for the problem in the half (generate the time seq) and the another half is to bind it with the matrix and keep the same class for numbers.

thanks in advance 
yaseen

Comment: @yaseen I am not exactly following your description.  Can you post that as a new question?

Comment: Thanks akrun , I put as.numeric before binding it with the matrix to solve the problem of changing the class of matrix to char.
v1 <- as.numeric(format(seq(as.POSIXct("00:00:00", format = "%H:%M:%S"),
                            length.out = 144, by = "10 min"), "%H%M")) 

thanks for your help